# How do I get the title of the current active window using c#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I'd like to know how to grab the Window title of the current active window (i.e. the one that has focus) using C#.

Comment: Were you trying to determine which window within your application has focus or which window of any application has focus?

Comment: this is relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423234/make-a-form-not-focusable-in-c-sharp/2428108#2428108 so if you wanted a button click to do it then it's worth making sure your form doesn't take focus.

Answer (score 191, accepted):

See example on how you can do this with full source code here:

http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/08/get-current-window-handle-and-caption-with-windows-api-in-c/

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder text, int count);

private string GetActiveWindowTitle()
{
    const int nChars = 256;
    StringBuilder Buff = new StringBuilder(nChars);
    IntPtr handle = GetForegroundWindow();

    if (GetWindowText(handle, Buff, nChars) > 0)
    {
        return Buff.ToString();
    }
    return null;
}
```

---

**Edited** with @Doug McClean comments for better correctness.

Comment: Don't forget to be a good citizen.  http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2007/07/27/4072156.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2008/10/06/8969399.aspx have relevant info.

Comment: a newb note, to get it to run, `using System.Runtime.InteropServices;`  and re where to put the dll import and static extern lines. pasting it within the class

Comment: @smink How get Active foreground window for specific user (let's say process runs as service).

Comment: Site you've linked to isn't available. Here is (possibly) web archive of it: https://web.archive.org/web/20150814043810/http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/08/get-current-window-handle-and-caption-with-windows-api-in-c/

Comment: Also, I want my app to be notified every time foreground window will change. Is there any event for that?

Comment: this works perfectly when the text is in english. but when the text is hebrew I get question marks instead of the hebrew text. is there a way around that?

Comment: Can I use this to access the ```SaveFileDialog```, I want to access the dialog window and want to set its file location, filename and click the save button programmatically..

Answer (score 19):

If you were talking about WPF then use:

```
 Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().SingleOrDefault(w => w.IsActive);
```

Comment: If the entire application isn't active (another program has focus), then no window will have IsActive set to true.

Comment: Actually that could be wrong, in my case I was trying to access the Window array on a non-UI thread. However, also see this in case I am still right: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/654c74fe-0a88-425f-99cd-ccf97ff234bc/active-window-of-an-inactive-application?forum=wpf

Answer (score 11):

Based on [GetForegroundWindow function | Microsoft Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633505(VS.85).aspx):

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder text, int count);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
static extern int GetWindowTextLength(IntPtr hWnd);

private string GetCaptionOfActiveWindow()
{
    var strTitle = string.Empty;
    var handle = GetForegroundWindow();
    // Obtain the length of the text   
    var intLength = GetWindowTextLength(handle) + 1;
    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(intLength);
    if (GetWindowText(handle, stringBuilder, intLength) > 0)
    {
        strTitle = stringBuilder.ToString();
    }
    return strTitle;
}
```

It supports UTF8 characters.

Answer (score 5):

Loop over `Application.Current.Windows[]` and find the one with `IsActive == true`.

Comment: Wouldn't this only work for the windows in the current .Net application?

I think d4nt wants to get the title of the current active window on the desktop, no matter what application it belongs to.

Answer (score 3):

Use the Windows API. Call `GetForegroundWindow()`.

`GetForegroundWindow()` will give you a handle (named `hWnd`) to the active window.

Documentation: [GetForegroundWindow function | Microsoft Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633505(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If it happens that you need the ***Current Active Form from your MDI application***: (MDI- Multi Document Interface).

```
Form activForm;
activForm = Form.ActiveForm.ActiveMdiChild;
```

Answer (score -4):

you can use process class it's very easy.
use this namespace

```
using System.Diagnostics;
```

if you want to make a button to get active window.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
       Process currentp = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
       TextBox1.Text = currentp.MainWindowTitle;  //this textbox will be filled with active window.
    }
```

Comment: This is wrong. It will show the title of your program not of the current active window.