# PerformClick on custom button will not work

Tags: c#, button

I have a custom class of a button and when I trigger `PerformClick` for any of my custom buttons, nothing happens. This is the code:

Declaration of my custom class

```
public class NonFocusButton : Button
{
    public NonFocusButton()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, false);
    }
}

List<NonFocusButton> buttons = new List<NonFocusButton>();
```

This is the `p` function:

```
void p()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        NonFocusButton aux = new NonFocusButton();
        aux.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Britannic Bold", 15.75F,    
        System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point,   
            ((byte)(0)));
        aux.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(192, 43);
        aux.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        aux.UseWaitCursor = false;
        aux.Visible = false;
        buttons.Add(aux);
        this.Controls.Add(aux);
    }            

    // button start

    buttons[0].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(410, 168);
    buttons[0].Text = "START GAME";
    buttons[0].Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button0_Click);
}

private void button0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}

buttons[0].PerformClick(); // will not work
```

Comment: Show more complete code.  There is not enough context here to figure out where the problem lies...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are buttons declared and filled? This is how I have it, and it works.

```
// declaration  
List<Button> butons = new List<Button>();

// calling  
buttons.Add(new Button());  
p();
buttons[0].PerformClick();
```

**Edit:**

The button has to get focus before it can be clicked.
Why not do something like:

```
button0_Click(buttons[0], EventArgs.Empty);
```

or just call `Close()` from wherever you are calling `PerformClick()`.

Comment: I have to PerformClick on every button I created and hoped that PerformClick might work.

Answer (score 1):

The `Button` `PerformClick` source code is:

```
public void PerformClick() {
    if (CanSelect) {
        bool validatedControlAllowsFocusChange;
        bool validate = ValidateActiveControl(out validatedControlAllowsFocusChange);
        if (!ValidationCancelled && (validate || validatedControlAllowsFocusChange))
        {
            //Paint in raised state...
            //
            ResetFlagsandPaint();
            OnClick(EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

And `CanSelect`:

```
public bool CanSelect {
    // We implement this to allow only AxHost to override canSelectCore, but still
    // expose the method publicly
    //
    get {
        return CanSelectCore();
    }
}

internal virtual bool CanSelectCore() {
    if ((controlStyle & ControlStyles.Selectable) != ControlStyles.Selectable) {
        return false;
    }

    for (Control ctl = this; ctl != null; ctl = ctl.parent) {
        if (!ctl.Enabled || !ctl.Visible) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

My guess as to the restriction is the `Selectable` flag was used instead of adding another control flag such as `AllowsPerformClick`.

Instead of using `PerformClick`, you could use reflection, e.g.

```
MethodInfo methodOnClick = typeof(Button).GetMethod("OnClick", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);

// and then...

methodOnClick.Invoke(myButton, new Object[] { EventArgs.Empty });
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just override the `PerformClick` event and temporary make the button selectable to perform the event execution like that:

```cs
public new void PerformClick()
{
    SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, true);
    base.PerformClick();
    SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, false);
}
```

In your case the complete code would be:

```cs
public class NonFocusButton : Button
{
    public NonFocusButton()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, false);
    }

    public new void PerformClick()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, true);
        base.PerformClick();
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, false);
    }
}
```

With that you won't need to make any other changes to rest of your project code.