# How to always keep browser on focus

Tags: c#, geckofx

When I click radio button or navigate through tabs my geckofx web browser loose focus. I can get back to focus by using browser.Focus() it works well but if there is for example two tabs 1tab and 2tab. On 2tab is my webbrowser. When I go to tab1 my browser in tab2 loose focus and command browser.Focus() wont work. Its really annoying that everytime I do some stuff on my UI gecko loose focus. Is there any way how I could keep it ALWAYS on focus?

Thanks.

Edit:
I thinked about making UI elements not to focus on them so browser wont loose its focus.
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6741544/c-sharp-stop-button-from-gaining-focus-on-click)
Found this, used that class and it works with buttons. Ill try to do this on tabs.

Comment: Did you try the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple. First add this code on `Form_load` :

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.TabIndex = 0;
            webBrowser1.Focus();
        }
```

Then make all other controls' Tabstop property to false. And on every controls clicking event add this code : `webBrowser1.Focus();`

For example I use this code for Button and RadioButton.

```
private void radioButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        radioButton1.TabStop = false;
        webBrowser1.Focus();
        webBrowser1.LostFocus += webBrowser1_LostFocus;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.TabStop = false;
        webBrowser1.Focus();
        webBrowser1.LostFocus += webBrowser1_LostFocus;
    }
```

Do this for all other controls in your form. You also need to define `webBrowser1_LostFocus` void for that.

```
void webBrowser1_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Focus();
    }
```

Update : You can also make a void for focusing. Then use this void in everywhere you want. Try this :

```
public void SetFocus(Control webbrowser)
{
 // Set focus to the control. 
   if(webbrowser.CanFocus)
   {
      webbrowser.Focus();
   }
}
```

Comment: I actually tried putting .Focus(); everywhere. When my browser loose focus it fastly turns on focus again. What I wanted to achieve is to never loose focus on that browser. I tried javascripts and tried to make all UI elements no focusable but that didnt worked.
Thanks for you help.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. Since I couldnt find any other ways to keep browser on focus Ill mark this as answer. Thanks again.