# Button remains in pressed state (highlighted) after touch

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button, touch

I have several forms with navigation buttons and when I select a button the selection will remain when the form changes.

This is just an example of code. I'm programming in C# with WPF.
I have uploaded 3 images to improve my explanation: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNERw.jpg .

```
private void CheckClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  formManager.showABATE();
}
```

I have a pages with global buttons (image 1). When I touch the `Button`, which is handled by `CheckClick` (Image 2), the next page is properly loaded (`formManager.showABATE`). But In that second page (image 3), the global `Button` still appears selected (focus, I guess).

Comment: Possible duplicate question : [C# Stop Button From Gaining Focus on Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6741544/c-sharp-stop-button-from-gaining-focus-on-click)

Comment: I tried that way and it didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried to disable press and hold feature? `<Button Stylus.IsPressAndHoldEnabled="False" />`

Comment: I've already try that option. Just happen 2 in 10 touchs, for example.

Comment: For people arriving late to this question (like me), the issue here is not the focus, but the fact that the cursor is lingering above the button after a touch event and this causes the mouse-over effect to be active.