# How to access correctly a return bool value in C#?

Tags: c#, boolean, return

**UPDATED FULL CODE**

I am trying a simple code sample that returns the windowhandle of the focused window but can't seem to get back the value in the textbox.

```
class ApplicationExecution
{
    public static bool MyWindow()
    {
        var activatedHandle = GetForegroundWindow();
        if (activatedHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            return false;       // No window is currently activated
        }

        var procId = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
        int activeProcId;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(activatedHandle, out activeProcId);


        return activeProcId == procId;
    }


    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr handle, out int processId);

}
```

I tried to access it like so

```
ApplicationExecution esma = new ApplicationExecution();
textbox1.text = esma;
```

as well as

```
 textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(ApplicationsWPF.ApplicationExecution.MyWindow());
```

**I Get either true or false and not the GetForegroundWindow values that the function is suppose to return**

Comment: Yes I am trying to get the activeiD or window

Answer (score 4):

You've defined `MyWindow` as a `static` method, therefore you need to access it through the class:

```
textbox1.Text = ApplicationExecution.MyWindow().ToString();
```

See [static (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/98f28cdx.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

either make MyWindow nonstatic, and:

```
textbox1.Text =esma.MyWindow();
```

or:

```
textbox1.Text=ApplicationExecution.MyWindow();
```

But as you explained now, you need the string with the Window name.

remove your hole MyWindow() Method and replace it with the private string GetActiveWindowTitle() method that can be found in the accapted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115868/how-do-i-get-the-title-of-the-current-active-window-using-c)

then write:

```
textbox1.Text=esma.GetActiveWindowTitle();
```

Comment: esma. only has "Equals" "GethashCode" "ToString" and "GetType" it does NOT have the MyWindow ?

Comment: then either make MyWindow nonstatic, or: textbox1.Text=ApplicationExecution.MyWindow();

Comment: This works; however, only returning a true or false VS the actual assigned values

Comment: if you want to get an integer, you should define a method, that returns an integer.

Comment: This is a sample code that is suppose to return the title of the focused window! I haven't done any modifications to it !

Comment: @xterminal0 so you just need the title of the active window?

Comment: Yes, I am trying a sample code to notify the user of the focused window title. If I set the return value as an int or string it just returns a number VS the actual text of the title

Answer (score 1):

Because you have marked the method as `static`.
You do not need to create an instance.

```
textbox1.Text = ApplicationExecution.MyWindow().ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the update to your original question, you could just change the signature of `MyWindow` to return an `int` and then return the value of `activeProcId`:

```
class ApplicationExecution
{
    public static int MyWindow()
    {
        ....

        return activeProcId;
    }

    ....
}
```

You may also want to rename the method to MyProcessId for clarity after making this change, but I know you said this is just a sample you're trying out.

Comment: This works; however, setting it to string or int just returns a number and not the actual string of the Window title?

Comment: You need to be explicit when you post a question on here. There's nothing in your original post about wanting to get the window title.