# Detect active/focused window in C#

Tags: c#, windows, media-player, gesture-recognition

How would I be able to detect what window is active and currently being focused on in C#?
Likes lets take Windows Media player for example. How would I detect if that window is currently up and being focused on in C#?

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115868/how-do-i-get-the-title-of-the-current-active-window-using-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Win32 `GetForegroundWindow` for this. However, this will only get you a handle (a `HWND`). You will need to use further P/Invoke methods to actually do something useful with this.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633505(v=vs.85).aspx for more information on `GetForegroundWindow` and http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getforegroundwindow for how to access this from C#.