# Why does System.Diagnostic.Process throw exception when switching apps using windows task bar icon?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-8.1

I'm currently developing an app that uses `System.Diagnostics.Process` to get the Window Title of the Current Active App or the App on the ForeGround. Now, this is fine and working with the current code I have until I came across with this issue. This `NullReferenceException` occurs if I switch my app using the task bar icon instead of the minimized button of the app window.

Edit:
It maybe confusing if I don't raise this up. So basically `NullReferenceException` is caused by `(title.Equals(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowTitle))`

title variable is null due to

```
String title = GetActiveWindowTitle();
```

GetActiveWindowTitle() returns null. And this uses `Window.GetForegroundWindow();` And for some reason using taskbar icons to switch up, this `Window.GetForegroundWindow();` method returns nothing.

[image]

[image]

Originally I used this

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
```

To get what I need. But I'm still having the same issue when switching app using the task bar icon. The only difference with using this code is that the exception is this 
`A first chance exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.dll`

My operating system is Windows 8.1.

Any inputs is greatly appreciated.

**Update**
The answer from @KcDoD was somewhat correct. And since the `NullReferenceException` was actually part of my question I will mark it as the Answer. And it also guides me a lot to figure out what's going on.

Basically, on my application I call this method `GetActiveWindowTitle()` within `WinEventProc(IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint eventType, IntPtr hwnd, int idObject, int idChild, uint dwEventThread, uint dwmsEventTime)`. WinEventProc() is a delegate method that triggers when you switch window. And it turns out that by calling `GetForegroundWindow();` or `GetActiveWindowTitle()` the process is not active yet that's why when it goes to get the Active application or Process it gives/return null.

Best regards

Comment: GetActiveWindowTitle returns null. We cannot see GetActiveWindowTitle. Only you can answer this. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Problem is related to the String you are trying to Equal with `MainWindowTitle` . That means the `title` variable/field.

You should check `tite` for `null` before trying to use `Equal`

Additionally : Here is a program using answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115868/how-do-i-get-the-title-of-the-current-active-window-using-c)

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
      String answ;

      while (true)
      {
           answ = GetActiveWindowTitle();
           if (answ == null)
           {
               Console.WriteLine("NO active program");
           }
           else {
              Console.WriteLine(answ);
           }
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
       }

 }


 [DllImport("user32.dll")]
 static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

 [DllImport("user32.dll")]
 static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder text, int count);

 static private string GetActiveWindowTitle()
 {
    const int nChars = 256;
    StringBuilder Buff = new StringBuilder(nChars);
    IntPtr handle = GetForegroundWindow();

    if (GetWindowText(handle, Buff, nChars) > 0)
    {
        return Buff.ToString();
     }
     return null;
  }
```

Answer : If there is no process selected then this will return null.  I think that's the answer for your question.

Comment: Yes I agree with you, if we focus on the exception but the root cause of it is that on my code  String title = GetActiveWindowTitle(); That methods returns null.

Comment: I think you are using this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115868/how-do-i-get-the-title-of-the-current-active-window-using-c   And you can see that it retun null for falure case :)

Comment: Not exactly! But Yea- pretty much the same codes and to what I'm trying to do. Using the codes from the link produces the same issue.

Comment: Strange , I added a small program I just created,, it return current window even when I switch programs using task bar

Comment: hmmmm- strange, what kind of app did you put this on? console/windows service/windows forms? Cause I think that will matter. Mine is windows forms.

Comment: @Shen Lance Check updated answer :) You will get a NULL when you don't have any selected process :) i think that's your answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71933/discussion-between-shen-lance-and-kcdod).